# JQuery toggle function not loading on click, only on 3rd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click the burger navigation I am trying to have the menu info drop down after the background fades in. But when I click the nav it doesn't work immediately. Only fading. After successive clicks it works. What am I doing wrong here? How can I get it working on the first click.

https://jsfiddle.net/mo16z57j/

```
// variables
var $header_top = $('.header-top');
var $nav = $('nav');


// toggle menu 
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
  $('.navOpen')
  .css('opacity', 0).delay(800)
  .slideDown('slow')
  .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
  ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
$header_top.find('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open-menu');
    $('.navOpen')
        .css('opacity', 0).delay(800)
        .show()
        .slideDown('slow')
        .animate(
            { opacity: 1 },
            { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
    ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: That's the one.